# mySQL Query optimisation LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to acquire some data from a questions table and then LEFT JOIN product answers. I need the list of all questions in a particular category (a total of 16 categories out of approximately 200 categories) and then list the product answers next to the questions for a certain product id.

```
SELECT `questions`.`id`, `questions`.`text`, `questions`.`catalogue_id`, `productanswers`.`answer` 

FROM `questions` 

LEFT JOIN `productanswers` ON `productanswers`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id` 

AND product_id = '2001682' 

WHERE `catalogue_id` IN (1234912,1234913,1234914) 

ORDER BY `catalogue_id`
```

which returns as I would expect approximately 17 results. Questions without an answer for this product are filled with Null, great!

The problem is that the query takes approximately 23 seconds to execute :-o making a full query with all catalogue questions impossible.

How can I optimise the query, or do you have any other ideas?

Thanks,
Taff

Comment: can you please add table columns and "explain" output to question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a composite (multiple column) index on the `question_id` and `product_id` together:

```
ALTER TABLE productanswers ADD KEY(question_id, product_id)
```

Note: You might want to switch the column order in the index, depending on the selectivity of `question_id` vs `product_id`

For more on composite indexes see the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Well, you learn something every day! That made a _slight_ difference, it went from over 23 seconds to 0.0077 ;-) Thanks Scrum Meister.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you should have indexes on all the your id columns but I guess you have this. Another source for information is the explain statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: My id columns are all set as primary key. Adding an index to the same column gives me a warning in phpmyadmin. Analyze Table gives me a status of OK. What would you recommend?